# Adding Admob in libgdx project

Tags: android, libgdx, admob, google-play-services

How can I add AdMob to my LibGdx project in 2018, I know that I need to add google play services, but after adding i have exception.

[image: screen]

How to add google play services without exceptions?

Comment: Can you please update this question with more details? How are you building this project? What specific command led to this exception?

Also, please include the text of the exception, and give us some details on how exactly you have added google play services. What file did you modify? What text did you add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the error message you posted a screenshot of (which is discouraged by the way, better to post the message as text), your `minSdkVersion` is set to `9` when it needs to be at least `14`. This is because the library requires it to be.

Change the `minSdkVersion`in your manifest file, see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element).

Answer (score 0):

Exception is self explaining you get error because library uses higher SDK version than you have declared in manifest. In manifest change "minSdkVersion" to 14 or you can change library version like so `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.+`